# Saved search not returning shipment package join in php toolkit

Tags: php, netsuite

I've created a saved search that returns shipping info. From the netsuite site I see the shipment package fields with the data. However, when I pull the saved search using the php toolkit I'm only getting back the basic and customer join. No package info. Anyone got any suggestions? Using a pretty standard SS request:

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, $count);
$search = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();
$search->savedSearchId = $id;
$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;
$page = new SearchMoreWithIdRequest();
$sr = $service->search($request);
```

FYI, I also tried pulling the result fields as a formula (text) but still not getting anything other than basic and customer join.

Here is my criteria and results if any one want to compare:

Criteria: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nejE4.png

Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YarDV.png

Answer (score 0):

In your preferences, make sure bodyFieldsOnly is set to false.

Comment: $service->setSearchPreferences(false, $count); is set to false.